# OnReceive call not working Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, function-calls, phone-call

I have a class which the code as follows:

```
public class CallManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.i("onReceive","here");
    }
}
```

Permissions on the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Receiver intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name="com.ram.tapdetector.CallManager">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

For some reason, nothing is getting logged from the onReceive function?

How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I assume you have an `Activity` in your app and you've launched it at least once?

Comment: Yes, my application fits all that criteria

Comment: @rohfosho, what action are you and Nash actually trying to detect? In the last post, it said "to see when my phone is called".

Comment: Yeah, when the phone is receiving a call, the onReceive() function should execute. @MikeM.

Comment: @rohfosho : One more thought - is your app installed on the SD card? If so it's never going to receive the broadcast. The reason is the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is sent before the SD card is mounted.

Comment: @Squonk how do i know if my app is installed on the SD card?

Comment: @Squonk and how can I make sure that the app is not installed on the SD card?

Comment: @rohfosho : Oh wait, I just read your previous comment. The `CallManager` receiver is never going to be called for an incoming call if the only action in the `<intent-filter>` is the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. As for knowing if it's installed on the SD card or not - if you specified `preferExternal` for installation location it may well be installed there. You can check it in Settings -> Apps (or Settings -> Manage applications)

Comment: What other action do I need in the <intent-filter> to accomplish this?

Comment: @rohfosho : Look at the `TelephonyManager` docs for `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: @Squonk can you help me out, I'm completely lost

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

for `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Checkout the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED).

As far as I see everything else should be ok.

**p.s.**: if you want to receive a broadcast event for incoming calls, use permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and declare your intent filter with

```
<receiver 
  android:name="com.ram.tapdetector.CallManager"
  android:enabled="true">   
    <intent-filter
      android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Check this nice [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) for more.

Comment: The onReceive function still is not being called after this?

Comment: Dear rohfosho, could you please provide some more code that surrounds your `CallManager` class. What I'm after is, maybe you have a typo in the package name or your class is a nested class. Nested classes have to be static and you need to declare them slightly different in the manifest. p.s. see comment above reg. incoming call receivers.

Comment: the code is basically up there^ I want to detect when a call is being recieved and I want to be able to answer/reject the call. But the onRecieve function is not being called no matter what.

Comment: @rohfosho: I cannot see your package declaration and I cannot see whether `CallManager` is a nested class. That can make a big difference ;) ... well, apart from that: add a tag `android:enabled="true"` to be sure the receiver is available on all platforms and add a priority, e.g. `android:priority="1000"` may be default priority is not high enough or another app (Hangouts is for example quite greedy: it uses MAXINT for short messages). See updates above .... if that doesn't work I can only think of a firmaware issue. Do you use a custom ROM?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

1) In your  element:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`
```

2) In your  element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.CallManager">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

`
In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
`    package com.example;

public class CallManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.i("onReceive","here");
    }
    }`
```

if you are using HTC mobile-

Along with

```
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  `
```

also use,

```
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />`
```

HTC devices dont seem to catch BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: I have used all of these things, and yet the application doesn't work. Do I need a service to use this? Or can it work without that?

Comment: one questions , which mobile are you using to test it? post your code to pathak.ims@gmail.com, I will look in to it and resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with flags:

```
android:enabled="true" 
android:exported="true"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This question is outdated, but I have a suggest anyway.
Be carefull, you have twice times the permission :

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

This could generate some errors when you try to run your application.